# Error al actualizar varios clientes con Socket.io

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, socket.io

Tengo una calendario(fullCalendar.io), después de crear/actualizar un evento, guardo en la BD y refresco el calendario:

```
function refreshEvent()
{
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
};
```

No tengo problemas con esto.

Implementé socket.io, y haciendo pruebas, desde Navegador1 cuando refresco el calendario mediante la función anterior, se actualiza en Navegador2 pero en Navegador1 genera un error "*there was an error while fetching events!*"

La creación del calendario está así:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      windowResize: function(view) {},
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'agendaWeek'
      },
      allDaySlot: false,scrollTime: '07:00:00',defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
      weekNumbers: true,navLinks: true,editable: true,eventLimit: true,
      droppable: true,
      eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
        var obj = {}
        obj.cAccion = 'M'
        obj.nId = event.id
        obj.cTitle = event.title;
        obj.cStart = assembleFullDate(event.start._i,'start');
        obj.cEnd = assembleFullDate(event.start._i,'end');
        obj.cClassName = selectClass(event.title);
        obj.idEvent = 0;
        var rF = cudObj("/cudEvents",obj);
      },
      eventReceive: function(event) {
        var obj = {}
        obj.cAccion = 'C'
        obj.nId = 0
        obj.cTitle = event.title;
        obj.cStart = assembleFullDate(event.start._i,'start');
        obj.cEnd = assembleFullDate(event.start._i,'end');
        obj.cClassName = selectClass(event.title);
        obj.idEvent = event.id;
        var rF = cudObj("/cudEvents",obj);
      },
      eventSources: [
        {
          url: '/dataSimulation',
          type: 'GET',
          error: function() {
            alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
          }
        }
      ],
      businessHours: {
        dow: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ],
        start: '07:00',
        end: '18:00',
      },
    });
```

En socket.js

```
function calendarChange()
{
    socket.emit('calendarChange');  
}
socket.on('newDates', function(){
    console.log("newDates");
    refreshEvent()
});
```

en www

```
socket.on('calendarChange', function(){
    console.log('calendarChange'.green);
    io.emit('newDates');
  });
```

Comment: Lo que me ayuda un poco, en _www_ cambié

`io.emit('newDates');` por `socket.emit('newDates');`

y en el html un función que invoque al socket cada cierto tiempo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente el error no estaba en fullCalendar sino que en la manera que implementé la conexión a la base de datos (por ende es otro el problema). En [StackOverflow_EN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51776451/error-when-updating-fullcalendar-whit-socket-io?noredirect=1#comment90513645_51776451) me preguntaron por el resultado de:

```
error: function(err) {
    console.log(err)
}
```

el resultado fue:
"*Global connection already exists. Call sql.close() first*"